# SVG Pattern Doesn't Show on Page

Tags: html, svg, jpeg

I am completely clueless, what is going wrong with my svg pattern. I defined it in the def section of the svg and then tried to reference it. But it doesn't show up once I include the svg in an img-tag. If I open it on itself in the browser everything is good though.

See the following examples: 
http://kijani.co/img/sketch/index.html
http://kijani.co/img/sketch/livingroom.svg

And my code:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="paper" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
    <image xlink:href="http://kijani.co/img/pattern/paper.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
<g id="background">
  <path id="paper" fill="url(#paper)" d="..."/>
</g>
```

This might be a really stupid question, but I am fairly new to svg and couldn't find a solution anywhere so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is svg's referencing mode probrem.
Using img element to display svg image is restrected for refering outer resources.
So you should use object element to display svg image, or embed pattern image into svg by data scheme format.

Comment: To clarify: this isn't anything unique about the pattern.  If you use a `<img>` tag to load your SVG, it will *only* load that one SVG file, and not any files (images, CSS, whatever) referenced from it.

Comment: thanks, that was it. Now I have to deal with svg view boxes in the code though. I hope there will be a better solution sometime in the future.